# for a given (0,1) vector, return the indices of all the (1,0) pairs for each row of this matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose the input is the following matrix,

```
[0,1,0,1;
 1,0,1,0]
```

Then, the expected output would be `(1,2,1), (1,2,3) (1,4,1), (1,4,3), (2,1,2) (2,1,4), (2,3,2), (2,3,4)`
The reason is that: in the first row, there are four ordered (1,0) pairs, whose indices are `(2,1), (2,3), (4,1) and (4,3).`. Similarly, in the second row, there are four ordered (1,0) pairs, whose indices are `(1,2), (1,4), (3,2) and (3,4).`
I now how to code this in matlab row by row.

```
>> a=[ 0,1,0,1; 1,0,1,0]

a =

     0     1     0     1
     1     0     1     0

>> b=a(1,:);
>> b

b =

     0     1     0     1

>> x1=find(b==1)

x1 =

     2     4

>> x0=find(b==0)

x0 =

     1     3

>> [X,Y]=meshgrid(x1,x0);
>> c=[X(:),Y(:)]

c =

     2     1
     2     3
     4     1
     4     3

>> d=[ repmat(1, [4,1])  c  ]

d =

     1     2     1
     1     2     3
     1     4     1
     1     4     3
```

With for loop, this can be solved. My question is: do you think you can code this in matlab without for loops? Many thaks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with some clever use of `meshgrid`.

```
a = [0,1,0,1;1,0,1,0];
[r0, c0] = ind2sub(size(a), find(a == 0)); % row and column of every 0
[r1, c1] = ind2sub(size(a), find(a == 1)); % row and column of every 1
[R0, R1] = meshgrid(r0, r1);
[C0, C1] = meshgrid(c0, c1);
idx = (R0 == R1); % consider only entries whose rows match
list = [R0(idx), C1(idx), C0(idx)]
```

Output:

```
list =

     1     2     1
     1     4     1
     2     1     2
     2     3     2
     1     2     3
     1     4     3
     2     1     4
     2     3     4
```